# read structure in function from list in c

Tags: c, list, struct

I'm writing some structure information in a list. The structure is Pstatus and it is global defined as pGlobal. Now I want to read from this list with pGlobal in function getStatus() but that did not work. So I created another definition pGlobal2 but that makes a lot of problems. I want to read out my list but I get some false informations. In this list the pids of the running processes are stored but when I read it out I only get the last pid and information but it I get it as much as pids are stored. If there are 5 pids stored in this list, I get the last one 5 times. I think thats because I've got pGlobal and pGlobal2. Is anybody able to help me?

```
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <errno.h>


    #include "utils.h"
    #include "listen.h"
    #include "wortspeicher.h"
    #include "kommandos.h"
    #include "frontend.h"
    #include "parser.h"
    #include "variablen.h"

    int interpretiere(Kommando k, int forkexec);
    int interpretiere_einfach(Kommando k, int forkexec);
    int getStatus();
    Pstatus pGlobal;
    Pstatus *pGlobal2;

    Liste procTable;


    int aufruf(Kommando k, int forkexec){

        int kind_status, i;

      /* Programmaufruf im aktuellen Prozess (forkexec==0)
         oder Subprozess (forkexec==1)
      */

      if(forkexec){
        int pid=fork();

        switch (pid){
        case -1:
          perror("Fehler bei fork"); 
          return(-1);
        case 0:
          if(umlenkungen(k))
        exit(1);
          do_execvp(k->u.einfach.wortanzahl, k->u.einfach.worte);
          abbruch("interner Fehler 001"); /* sollte nie ausgeführt werden */
        default:
          if(k->endeabwarten) {
              /* So einfach geht das hier nicht! */

              /* schreibt die PID, den Namen und den Status in die Tabelle */  
              pGlobal = erzeugeProzess (pid, k->u.einfach.worte[0], "RUNNING"); /*k->u.einfach.worte[0] */
              /* Debug: print
              printf("\npid: %d\tstatus: %s\n", p.pid, p.status); 
              */
              i = listeLaenge(procTable);
              procTable = listeAnfuegen(procTable, &pGlobal);
              if(listeLaenge(procTable) <= i) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Fehler beim Schreiben in die Liste!");
              }

              /* Debug printf: Bis hierhin wird alles ordentlich in die Liste geschrieben! */
              /*test = listeKopf(procTable);
              printf("pointer1: %p",test);
              printf("\npid: %d\tstatus: %s\n", test->pid, test->status); */


              waitpid(pid, &kind_status, 0);
                if(WIFEXITED(kind_status)){
                    printf("Kind mit der PID %d wurde beendet\n",pid);
                    if (WEXITSTATUS(kind_status) == 0) {
                        /** setze status exit(0) */ 
                        printf("Kind erfolgreich\n");
                        pGlobal = statusAendern(pGlobal,pid,"exit(0)"); 
                    } 
                    /* nicht erfolgreiche ausgeführt */
                    else 
                    {
                        /** setze status exit(1) */ 
                        printf("Kind nicht erfolgreich\n");
                        pGlobal = statusAendern(pGlobal,pid,"exit(1)"); 
                    }
                }
                else if(WIFSIGNALED(kind_status)){
                    printf("Kind mit der PID %d wurde durch Signal abgebrochen. Signalnummer: %d\n",pid, WTERMSIG(kind_status));
                    pGlobal = statusAendern(pGlobal,pid,"signal"); 
                }
          }
          else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Programm nicht beendet\n");
            fprintf(stdout, "PID: %i\n", pid);
          }  
          return 0;
        }
      }

      /* nur exec, kein fork */
      if(umlenkungen(k))
        exit(1);
      do_execvp(k->u.einfach.wortanzahl, k->u.einfach.worte);
      abbruch("interner Fehler 001"); /* sollte nie ausgeführt werden */
      exit(1);
    }


    int interpretiere_einfach(Kommando k, int forkexec){    

      char **worte = k->u.einfach.worte;
      int anzahl=k->u.einfach.wortanzahl;

      /* gibt den Status der Subprozesse zurück */
      if (strcmp(worte[0], "status")==0){

          /* NYI */
        getStatus();

      }

      return aufruf(k, forkexec);
    }

    int getStatus() {

        Liste temp, temp2;

        fprintf(stdout, "---------------------\n----Statustabelle----\n---------------------\n");

        temp = procTable;

        printf("laenge der liste: %d\n",listeLaenge(temp));

        /*fprintf(stdout, "Pid: %d", p->pid);*/

        if(listeLaenge(temp) < 1) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Liste ist leer.\n");
            return 0;
        }

        while(temp != NULL){

            pGlobal2 = listeKopf(temp);

            /*printf("check: %d\n",pGlobal2->check);*/

            if(pGlobal2->check < 1) {
                fprintf(stdout,"PID: %d, Programm: %s, Status: %s\n",pGlobal2->pid, pGlobal2->name, pGlobal2->status);
            }

            if(strcmp(pGlobal2->status, "RUNNING") != 0) {
                pGlobal2->check = 1;
            }   

            /*if(strcmp(pGlobal2->status, "RUNNING") == 0) {
                printf("eintrag behalten");
                listeAnfuegen(temp2, pGlobal2);
            }*/


            /* wenn status != running -> p.checked() */

            temp = listeRest(temp);
          }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

I've got the struct

```
typedef struct {
int pid;        /* Prozess ID */
char* name;     /* Prozess Name (Programm) */
char* status;   /* Status des Programms */
int check;      /* bereits abgerufen? 1 - abgerufen, 0 - nicht abgerufen */
} Pstatus;
```

Listen:

```
typedef struct liste {
  void *kopf;
  struct liste *rest;
} *Liste;
```

listeKopf:

```
void* listeKopf(Liste l) { 
  if(l==NULL)
    abbruch("listeKopf(listeLeer) undefiniert");
  return l->kopf; 
}
```

listeAnfuegen:

```
Liste listeAnfuegen(Liste l, void* element){
  Liste neu=reserviere(sizeof (struct liste));
  neu->kopf = element;
  neu->rest = l;
  return neu;
}
```

Comment: Why have a global variable `pGlobal2` at all if you use it only locally?

Comment: When I tried to use it locally, I wasn't able to read from this list. So the global variable was a work around.

Comment: That's 355 lines of code. Would you mind trimming that down so only the relevant, misbehaving code, is shown (and still a workable example)?

Comment: In the code you posted, `pGlobal2` is initialised and used only inside one `while` block. In my opinion, you could easily make this local.

Comment: Also using it local does not solve the problem. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've provided long reams of information, but not the crucial stuff. So I'll assume that `erzeugeProzess` returns a structure `Pstatus`. You add nodes to your list like this:

```
pGlobal = erzeugeProzess(pid, k->u.einfach.worte[0], "RUNNING");
procTable = listeAnfuegen(procTable, &pGlobal);
```

So you always add the address of `pGlobal` to your list, which, of course always contains the contents assigned in the last call to `erzeugeProzess`. (That's also why your code didn't work with a local variable: The reference in the list was to somewhere on the stack, which very likely did not contain useful information.)

The solution is to make `erzeugeProzess` really create an object on the stack, e.g.:

```
Pstatus *proc_new(...)
{
    Pstatus *proc = malloc(sizeof(*proc));

    // initialise
    return proc;
}
```

This will create a new process with its own data on the heap, which you can assign to your list. You will need to `free` the proceses at some point, though.

Once you have done this, you won't need the global variables any more. Use local variables.You won't lose the reference, because you store it in the list:

```
Pstatus *p = proc_new(pid, k->u.einfach.worte[0], "RUNNING");
procTable = listeAnfuegen(procTable, p);
```

As a side note: Your code has some very awkward naming conventions. For example `erzeugeProzess` means `createProces`, but in your version, it doesn't create anything. (It is commonly assumed that functions that `create` or whose name contains `new` create stuff on the heap.)

Likewise, what you call `kopf` or `head` of your list, isn't its head. It's the data associated with one node in the list. The head would be its first element.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I like to change the status can I do this with a new process Pstatus *proc_change(Pstatus p, char* value) {
p->status = value;
return proc;
}
?? :)

Comment: You mean `return p`? You don't even need to return the pointer here, because you only change data in the same location. (This is different from your `listeAnfuegen`, where your new head is at a completely new location. Before and after calling `proc_change`, `p` has the same value.)